# Deshabilitar fecha en calendarView - android

Tags: java, android, date

Me gustaría que me ayudaran a deshabilitar las fechas posteriores al día de hoy en un calendar view. ¿Cómo podria hacerlo?

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
calendario=(CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.cvCalendario);
calendario.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,int month, int dayOfMonth) {

       //fechaSelect = year + "-" + month + "-" + dayOfMonth;
       fechaSelect = dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year;
       fechaCorrecta = year+"-"+"0"+(month+1)+"-"+dayOfMonth;
       Toast.makeText(ctx, fechaSelect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       Intent intent;
       intent = new Intent(ctx,Municipios.class);
       intent.putExtra("fechaSelect",fechaSelect);
       intent.putExtra("fechaCorrecta",fechaCorrecta);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas la documentación, esto lo puedes realizar por medio del método `Calendar.init()` :

Obtienes el año anterior:

```
Calendar anoAnterior = Calendar.getInstance();
anoAnterior .add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
```

defines el rango de fechas del año anterior hacia el día de hoy:

```
CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
Date diaActual = new Date();
calendar.init(anoAnterior, diaActual)
    .withSelectedDate(diaActual );
```

Con esto deshabilitamos las fechas posteriores al día de hoy.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas conveniente seria establecer un valor maximo de fecha que en este caso seria la fecha actual y solo asi podras manejar la fecha establecida y las anteriores o futuras fechas no estarn disponibles.
Aqui esta el codigo:

```
 JDateChooser chooser =  new  JDateChooser (); 
chooser . setMaxSelectableDate ( new  Date ()); 

chooser . setDateFormatString ( "dd-MM-yyyy" ); 

chooser . setDate ( new  Date ());
```